# can't understand this error (GET http://makeappdev.xyz/1e6ab715a3a95d4603.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)

Tags: angular

I just started learning Angular, Now I'm developping a small application to practise it, The back end side I developped it with Spring boot.

I did a service student to get all students from the DB mysql, the api rest is working.

this is the error that I got in the console :
analytics.js:1 GET http://makeappdev.xyz/1e6ab715a3a95d4603.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

### this is the component TS where I call my service to get the list from the server.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { StudentService } from '../services/student.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-list-student',
    templateUrl: './list-student.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list-student.component.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class ListStudentComponent implements OnInit {

    listStudent;
    currentStudent;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private studentService : StudentService) { }
        ngOnInit() {
        this.studentService.getListStudent();
        this.listStudent = this.studentService.listStudent;
    }
```

--

when I call the GET method directly from the componenet it works against when I try to put it on the service it does not work anymore

### below the service class

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StudentService {

    public listStudent;
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    public getAllStudent() {
        this.httpClient
            .get('http://localhost:8080/etudiants')
            .subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    this.listStudent = response;
                    console.log('Ok ! : ');
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log('Ko ! : ' + error);
                }
                );
    }
    public getListStudent() {
        this.getAllStudent();
        return this.listStudent;
    }
}
```

---

thank you in advance

Comment: It means the domain cannot be resolved, which you can further confirm here: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/makeappdev.xyz

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work unless you're having a connection probably with your endpoint. It could mean whatever domain your accessing needs to update their nameserver.

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED means that the domain name cannot be resolved. DNS (Domain Name System) is responsible for resolving domains, and every domain on the internet has a name server, which make it possible for the DNS’s to resolve Domain Names.

Are you using Chrome?  If so you can try and clear your host cache, or try a different browser.

Aside from that I would probably refactor this a bit.  You're invoking an asynchronous request, but passing a reference to a publicly stored value in your service to the component.  To clean this up you can pass an `Observable` back through to your component to access the response, as well as, store the list in the service for accessing afterwards.  I'd probably make the list in the service private though and provide a getter so it can't be updated directly.

You can try your endpoint with this Stackblitz and see if it still fails since it works using `reqres`, and this includes what I suggested above.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcu7my?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html